# Конвертация PHP в JS

Tags: javascript, php

Можно ли ,и как, данный PHP-скрипт полностью конвертировать в JS?

```
<?php
    $widget_id = 264589; // Идентификатор виджета, требуется для обращения к Widget API
    $secret_key = "B0a9gEMHMhNuAfA1iTTgLhGlubLBDD35"; // Секретный ключ виджета
    $public_key = "D55KyGh-NYud5V6bENifXPseR7Giyzd3"; // Публичный ключ виджета

    if($_POST["sbm"]) {
        if($_POST["ucaller-response"]) { // После успешной верификации номера телефона в виджете, мы автоматически добавляем поле в вашу форму с именем `ucaller-response`
            // Описание взаимодействия с Widget API описано в пункте 5.1
            // Здесь мы проверяем, действительно ли пользователь прошел верификацию номера телефона
            $response = file_get_contents("https://api.ucaller.ru/v1.0/verifyResponse?service_id=".$widget_id."&key=".$secret_key."&response=".$_POST["ucaller-response"]);
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
            if($response["status"]) {
                // Все верно! Этот пользователь проходил верификацию номера
                $phone_number = $response["phone"]; // Может получить номер телефона пользователя
                $phone_id = $response["phone"]; // Может получить идентификатор номера телефона
                // Регистрируем пользователя!
                echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы!";
            }
            else echo "Нет, вы передали неверные значения, попробуйте повторить попытку верификации номера в виджете";
        }
        else echo "Вам необходимо пройти проверку номера телефона";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POST` параметры не получится переделать на js поэтому данную функцию кидаете между тегами `script` на странице, и подставляете значения в переменные (код ниже). Плюс Вы должны понимать что все секретные ключи и т.д. будут видны пользователям. Не знаю зачем Вам это надо но вот код:

```js
//<script ...>
function getData() {
  var widget_id = 264589; // Идентификатор виджета, требуется для обращения к Widget API
  var secret_key = "B0a9gEMHMhNuAfA1iTTgLhGlubLBDD35"; // Секретный ключ виджета
  var public_key = "D55KyGh-NYud5V6bENifXPseR7Giyzd3"; // Публичный ключ виджета
  var sbm = <?php echo $_POST["sbm"] ?>;
  var ucallerResponse = <?php echo $_POST["ucaller-response"] ?>;
  var path = `https://api.ucaller.ru/v1.0/verifyResponse?service_id=${widget_id}&key=${secret_key}&response=${ucallerResponse}`;
  if (!sbm) {
    console.log('sbm not valid');
    return;
  }

  if (!ucallerResponse) {
    console.log('Вам необходимо пройти проверку номера телефона');
    return;
  }
  fetch(path, {method: 'get'})
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      if (data.status) {
        var phone_number = data.phone;
        var phone_id = data.phone;

        console.log('Вы успешно зарегистрированы');
      }
      else {
        console.log('Нет, вы передали неверные значения, попробуйте повторить попытку верификации номера в виджете');
      }

      return;
    });

}

getData();
//</script>
```

Comment: Что-то работает не так как надо...

Comment: @Matel ну запрос на сервер уходит проверяйте что У Вас в пост данных приходит попробуйте сначала жёстко их подставить за место `<?php echo $_POST["ucaller-response"] ?>` и т.д.

Comment: @Matel var sbm = <?php echo $_POST["sbm"] ?>;
  var ucallerResponse = <?php echo $_POST["ucaller-response"] ?>;
 в эти две переменные подставьте какие-нибудь правильные значения жестко строкой

Comment: а вы бы не могли на сайте посмотреть и сказать что нет?

Comment: @Matel что должно быть в $_POST["sbm"] и $_POST["ucaller-response"]?? какие значения приведите пример

Comment: как это можно сделать с учетем что открывающий тег формы - <form method="post" action="/index/" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adduser" onsubmit="try {return checksubmit(this);}catch(e){} this.sbm.disabled=true">

Comment: https://ucaller.ru/doc

Comment: <input class="manFlSbm" id="siF20" type="submit" name="sbm" value="Регистрация" />

Comment: @Matel вопрос мой был не об этом. После отправки формы Вы считываете два значения в файле обработки формы которые выглядят так:$_POST["sbm"] и $_POST["ucaller-response"], что в них хранится? какие значения, чтобы после отправки запроса вернулся корректный результат? Вы попросили перевести код на js а не настроить Вам api)

Comment: После заполнения формы обратной связи она должна отправиться по uri указанном в `action` там лежит данный скрипт (который указан в ответе), после отправки приходят данные которые были заполнены Вы их считываете через $_POST[...] и далее поставляете как я указал в ответе, далее идет запрос к api и приходит ответ

Comment: Запрос уходит на сервер, но приходит `status` false, потому что я не знаю какие корректные значения должны быть чтобы api вернул true. Их я и прошу Вас привести) чтобы просто их подставить и попробовать отправить запрос!

Comment: https://ucaller.ru/doc#api40